# Is System Version Temporal Tables in SQL Server Standard an expensive operation?

Tags: sql-server

This is how  we convert an existing  non temporal to temporal

```
CREATE SCHEMA History;   
    GO   
    ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy   
       ADD   
          SysStartTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN    
               CONSTRAINT DF_SysStart DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME()  
          , SysEndTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN    
               CONSTRAINT DF_SysEnd DEFAULT CONVERT(datetime2 (0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59'),   
          PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);   
    GO   
    ALTER TABLE InsurancePolicy   
       SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = History.InsurancePolicy))   
    ;
```

Can someone explain me this:

> Adding non-nullable columns with defaults to an existing table with
>   data is a size of data operation on all editions other than SQL Server
>   Enterprise Edition (on which it is a metadata operation). With a large
>   existing history table with data on SQL Server Standard Edition,
>   adding a non-null column can be an expensive operation.

I am using SQL Server Standard edition and how can it be an expensive operation by adding a non-null column field.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table

Comment: It's expensive because it needs to add this/these column(s) for every row in your table. This might (or might not) cause the data to be spread across more pages than the table currently consumes.

Comment: Adding a column with a default value, to an already populated table, is down the line of updating all of the records in the table.  It means that it's rearranging the physical records on the disks in one massive update.  It's a constraint on all of the alert logs as it's doing it all in one large transaction.  And it can (and most likely) cause a full-table lock escalation.

Comment: Expensive compared to what? If you need to track validity time, you'd have to add `start` and `end` columns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable columns can be added without changing the data records. They are simply `null` values by default and the individual records do not have to be modified.

Making any new fields non-nullable however, *which implicitly requires default values if you have existing records*, requires it to set the default value *on every single record*. Depending on the number of records, that need to be updated, this could definitely be "an expensive operation"*.

*Note: this applies to any table changes and not just Temporal Tables.